# SetReadOnly Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm having a hard time using `setReadonly` of CKEDITOR. I want to use `setReadonly` when the Editor is already loaded and ready to be used. I tried using `instanceReady`:

```
    var editor;
    CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ){
        editor = ev.editor;
        editor.setReadOnly( true );
    });
```

but this does not work, I tried using buttons like the sample is using and it works fine. Is there anyway to `setReadonly` automatically when the editor is ready to be used?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean by "does not work" that you are getting a javascript error? where is `messageID` created? You might want to try just using `$(this)` instead. What sample? You should update your question to link to what you are trying to pattern after. Finally, do you mean `setReadOnly(false);`?

Comment: @veeTrain by "does not work" means it does not do anything or gives errors. messageID(textarea's ID) is my Editor. Making `setReadOnly(false);` will turn of Read Only Mode. and I want it `ON`, so that the Textarea cannot be edited.

Comment: Interesting; could you show where `messageID` was created as a variable? If that is its ID on the element itself and you haven't created it yet, you would need to find it on that line. Have you put any indicators inside of your `instanceReady` such as an alert? That would help you know where your expectations are falling through.

Comment: well I changed `messageID` to `editor` like above. I tried alert inside `instanceReady` but that does not work either but I have codes that work inside `instanceReady`. I'll edit the code area above.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to create it as [readOnly](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.readOnly) instead of waiting for it to finish and then tell it to restart as readOnly.

For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="messageid" id="messageid">
    abc
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.replace('messageid', {readOnly: true} );  
 </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NxXbn/)

Comment: To people trying this; there is an annoying bug related to this in 3.6 where the undo functionality breaks in all browsers if this is used. See https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9290 to check if it's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see how does it work!! For me works right.

http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/readonly.html

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, use disabled tag in textarea.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="messageid" id="messageid" disabled="disabled">
    abc
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.replace('messageid');  
 </script>   
</body>
</html>
```